# Deprecated SubfieldBase's replacement to call to_python on assignment?

Tags: django

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#subfieldbase), `SubfieldBase` is going to be removed in 1.10 and replaced by `from_db_value()`

What puzzles me is this:

> Note that the new approach does not call the `to_python()` method on assignment as was the case with `SubfieldBase`.

I thought that was the main point of `SubfieldBase`. What is the best way to perform a validation on value assignment in >=1.9?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `to_python` by yourself. Just implement proper conversion in `from_db_value`. This function is now responsible for creating proper python representation from DB Value. For most of the fields it won't be needed, because DB backend will already perform conversion.

Comment: Thank you, I think the question should have been asked as "What is the best way to perform validation on value assignment". For example, `my_list_field = 'string'` should not be allowed